# How to tell if $f(x)=x^n|x|$ is twice differentiable or not by looking at the 2nd derivative?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I came across the following question in my test:

> Let $f:R\rightarrow R, f(x)=x^n|x|$. Then number of integer values of $n$ for which $f(x)$ is not a twice differentiable function in it's domain is?

---

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\phantom{-}x^{n+1} & \text{if}\; x\geq 0 \\
-x^{n+1} & \text{if}\; x < 0 \end{cases} $$

$$ f''(x) = \begin{cases} 
\phantom{-}n(n+1)x^{n-1} & \text{if}\; x\geq 0 \\
-n(n+1)x^{n-1} & \text{if}\; x < 0 \end{cases} $$

Now that we have the expression of $f''(x)$, how do we tell if it's defined or not without spending a lot of time as the test doesn't allow a lot of time per question.
When I looked at the solution, it directly concluded from the expression of $f''(x)$ that it's not defined at $n=0,1$ but I didn't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=0$ then $f''(0)$ is not defined.
If $n=1$ then $f''(0)$ is defined in such a way that $\lim_{x\to0}f''(x)$ does not exist.

If $n$ is any other integer, then $f''(0)$ is defined and $f''(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.